# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Video'

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm currently getting the core data error and an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance #'. I can't seem to figure out what is happening. Here's the code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

protocol FetchResultsControllerDelegate {
func dataReady()
}

class PNSClient: NSObject {

var pnsVideos = [Video]()
var delegate: FetchResultsControllerDelegate?

func getFeedVideos() {

    // Fetch the videos dynamically through the YouTube Data API
    Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.YouTubeURL, parameters: [Parameters.Part: Parameters.Snippet, Parameters.PlaylistId: Constants.UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID, Parameters.Key: Constants.API_KEY, Parameters.MaxResults : 50], encoding: .URL, headers: nil)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            let userID = response.objectForKey("items")
            print(userID)

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            var arrayOfPNSVideos = [Video]()

            for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {
                print(video)

                let videoObj = Video()
                videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as? String
                videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as? String
                videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as? String
                if let highUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.high.url") as? String {
                    videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = highUrl

                arrayOfPNSVideos.append(videoObj)
            }

            self.pnsVideos = arrayOfPNSVideos

            if self.delegate != nil {
                self.delegate?.dataReady()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If looking at the repo will help: [www.github.com/pbellot77/pop-nutshell](http://www.github.com/pbellot77/pop-nutshell)

Comment: On which line does the problem occur?

Comment: Unless something has changed, you can't instantiate a `NSManagedObject` with `Video()`.  It has to be inserted using the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: I get an error on line 51 of the PNSClient. I'm trying to store the objects directly into core data for reusability.

Comment: When I set break points at the exceptions, the app stops at line 51, 52 then crashes with a Thread 1: SIGABRT

Comment: I updated the repo. Now I'm getting an insertion error. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store objects into CoreData, you need to follow this pattern below.  I recommend you read a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) on CoreData, or the [docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_w_-e_e3NAhUJ-mMKHQ--DDYQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fwatchos%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FCoreData%2Findex.html&usg=AFQjCNFBboQt-mO9hxM7d72tn7Bn7mFQ5w).

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Video", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) 
// you need to make sure you have a reference to your CoreData managedObjectContext
    let videoObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as? Video
    videoObj.property1 = "some value"
    videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as? String

// etc ...


do {
    try managedObjectContext!.save()
}
catch {
    print("Error saving video changes: \(error)")
}
```